# WebView not loading?

Tags: ios, webview, tableview, segue

I am new to Objective c. I am learning about segue's and PrepareForSegue. So I have a table view with random links that the user has saved. I want to allow the user to click on the link and be taken to a web view to view the webpage. However, every time I click on a link the webpage is empty.

Table View. m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showArticle"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", _toDoItems[indexPath.row]];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:urlString];
```

WebView.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.url
                                   stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", request]]]];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
```

}

Comment: are you trying this on iOS 9.0?

Comment: It would be good if you could make your destinationViewcontroller the delegate of your web view. Then implement the UIWebView delegate methods of UIWebView and put a breakpoint in shouldStartLoadWithRequest: for example. Then you can debug if your web view is at least trying to load the request.

You could also implement webDidFinishLoading and the other delegate methods for UIWebViewDelegate.

Comment: Yes @Vishnugondlekar

Answer (score 0):

Add these keys to your info.plist. In ios 9 you must use https:// instead of http://

[image: Info.plist]

Here is the link for configuring App Transport Security 
[App Transport Security](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/)

Make sure your urlString return by this line must not be nil. It must be a valid url working in your browser:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", _toDoItems[indexPath.row]];
```